# Flutter - How to give GIF image on the native splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I'm creating a splash screen using the native splash screen package.

I tried to give a GIF image in the background of the splash screen. But it didn't work. Is there a way to render a GIF image in a full splash screen?

Code:

```
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.17

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#94f301"
  android_12:
    color: "#94f301"
  backgoround_image_android: assets/images/splash.gif
  fullscreen: true
```

Comment: try to check this package: dependencies:
  flutter_gifimage: ^2.0.0, I might be useful to show a GIF.

Answer (score 1):

you can use flutter_native_splash (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

and this is how to use it:

Add the flutter_native_splash package to your pubspec.yaml file and run `flutter pub get` to install it:

```
flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
```

In the pubspec.yaml file, add the following lines to define the splash screen settings:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.gif
  color: "#2b2b2b"
  android: true
  ios: true
  scale: "fill"
```

Run `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create` to generate the native splash screen files for Android and iOS.

In your main.dart file, add the following lines to import the flutter_native_splash.dart file and initialize the splash screen:

```
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.show(
    splashScreen: MySplashScreen(),
    duration: 3000,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Build and run your app to see the GIF image displayed on the native splash screen.

Note: Make sure to test the splash screen on actual devices, as some emulators may not display the native splash screen correctly.

Comment: Hi, is this still relevant? as I see show method doesn't exist. also this comment says gif is not supported. https://github.com/jonbhanson/flutter_native_splash/issues/587

Comment: @just10minutes hello, yes it's still relevant

Comment: I am getting error as show method does not exist. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: GIF is not supported for (IOS, Android) on this package, its for web only

Answer (score 1):

Add This package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

```
dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.2.0
```

Add this into **android/app/src/main/res/values**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="splash_color">#FFFFFF</color>
    </resources>
Also Add this into **android/app/src/main/res/drawable**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/splash_color"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Add the following code to the flutter_native_splash section of your pubspec.yaml file:**

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/images/splash.gif
  android: true
  ios: false
```